# How to write a removeError rest destructure function in typescript

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I want to write a function which can remove a key with a certain name from an object (use case is in react where i want to set new error state when a field is focussed

This is how i write it in javascript

```
removeError = (fieldName) => {
    const { error } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      const { [fieldName]: ommited, ...rest } = error;
      this.setState({ error: rest });
    }
  };
```

If i write it in typescript - how to write this line:

```
const { [fieldName]: ommited, ...rest } = error;
```

Comment: What type are you using for `state`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you to do this, the type of the `error` object in state will have to have all of its properties be *optional*, like this:

```typescript
interface ExampleState {
    error?: {       // <== This doesn't have to be optional, but from your code it is
        a?: string; // ***
        b?: string; // *** These have to be optional
        c?: string; // ***
    }
}
```

(You could also use `Record<string, string>` or similar for `Error`, but it wouldn't be as typesafe.)

Then the definition uses `keyof ExampleState["error"]` to give the right type to `fieldName`, and the rest is pretty much as you had it (I fixed the spelling of "omitted"):

```typescript
removeError = (fieldName: keyof ExampleState["error"]) => {
    this.setState(({error}) => {
        if (error) {
            const { [fieldName]: omitted, ...rest } = error;
            return { error: rest };
        }
        return null;
    });
};
```

Notice that since we're setting state based on existing state, it's best to use the callback form of `setState`

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4BRADxXABskBlGCgZwA3lTiS4jHFAD8ALjFSVAelVwAPAF5tcACoALYAGc4AEwhITtAOTxDKAG6sYEOACNWEMDGARaFB4AGk8AVywcPABPCDCoODQIc1ZgeFMJFSkURTgTGCg6AHNSOHU4ACoqzKzPXPzC2hKyjSqKg0NrVkcXODdPb19-QJ4arLR6guLS8raxgF8qRepKNB4UEzNObjA+aQ4GWnMzZHQYADoAYVxIWiR6TVF50O3eASEGAD4xMaIQCBcbCgsjgegAFJhgEgeOYAHLcJBKADWSFimHYXDegmESAA2vgZNB8ABdACUoO+4kotUkMGMJnOJiQMGxDDBYNEhKg83J2kpYxpcGA6LBXPJVMFgqStHyylxkOhcIRxKUuDSDHMoXO2qIsvmoOkwOgFGpktqRBg8Voyi5Sl18HmJrNkmWzrgFqtcFoYR4PCdNJ5-pdJuWQA)

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is a superset of javascript so any javascript code is valid in typescript, but you might need to declare types to remove warnings.

I'm suspecting you don't have the right type for your state, which is why you're getting some error, but it's hard to say without seeing that portion of your code.

Either way, by setting the right types, you should be able to make your code compile just fine, see this example:

```
type State = {error?: Record<string, string>};
let state: State = {};
const setState = (state: State) => undefined;

const removeError = (fieldName: string) => {
    const { error } = state;
    if (error) {
      const { [fieldName]: ommited, ...rest } = error;
      setState({ error: rest });
    }
  };
```

See for yourself in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8ICdMHtMH4AuKAJQgGM8ATAHgGdhMBLAOwHMAaKB59gPgC+AbgCwAKAA2EYNwRJicRCnTDxlFg27TFSKKgAUDJQrkQAlHr5QAriyoQAZqwhVRYtTg0zMEALY4ANwgAUWw8PSh9JwgJKgA5eF8IYh5WNgtkKzRxKFyodU00KCxcTCgBCKMkNzyoJgdIkrwLbLFa3IKZIoBtaNiEpIBdYhxfXyYkKi4AOlmfTQrUJswa9rptU30i5eJ5mQEzVdyBHPKhIA).

note: I just mocked react state for the purpose of this code snippet.

Comment: I would make `fieldName` more strict and use `keyof State['error']` or whatever type error has.